can ejs files be used with github pages?
I just want to publish my website that contains ejs files. I didn't publish any website before using github pages so what should I do for the ejs files? Because as my understanding github pages doesn't support ejs files, it only supports static files.
I tried to render each ejs file to html files but it cause some errors because I'm sending data from my database at the backend part and this data cause erros while rendering.

GitHub Pages does not support EJS (Embedded JavaScript) files directly because it only serves static content. EJS is a templating language that requires server-side rendering to process the templates and convert them into HTML before serving them to the client.

so it is not possible to use ejs files when using github-pages right? what should I do then should I never use ejs files I couldn't understand how to deal with ejs files if I want to publish my website on github.
